# How can you correctly create and modify a hashset of tuples in powershell?

Tags: powershell, set, hashset

I'm trying to make a hashset of 2-element (pair) tuples in PowerShell thus:

```
$MySet = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[System.Tuple]
```

Which *seems* to work:

```
$MySet.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     HashSet`1                                System.Object

$MySet.Add

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
bool Add(System.Tuple item)
void ICollection[Tuple].Add(System.Tuple item)
bool ISet[Tuple].Add(System.Tuple item)
```

But if I create a tuple and add it to the set:

```
$Tuple = [System.Tuple]::Create("Test", "Hello")
$MySet.Add($Tuple)
MethodException: Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1".
```

What's the way to go about this correctly?

Bonus: There's no [threadsafe version of hashset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/) - is there a way to modify/read hashsets in a threadsafe manner then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `[System.Tuple]::Create($a,$b)` *doesn't* actually create an instance of `[System.Tuple]`, but of `[System.Tuple[T1,T2]]` where `T1` is the type of `$a`, and `T2` is the type of `$b`.

Although they share part of the name, `[System.Tuple[T1,T2]]` is *not assignable* to `[System.Tuple]`, so we'll have to find another type argument for your `[HashSet]`.

Since your tuple item values are strings, go with `[System.Tuple[string,string]]`:

```
$set = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[System.Tuple[string,string]]]::new()
$tuple = [System.Tuple]::Create("Hello", "World")
$set.Add($tuple)
```

---

## BONUS ANSWER

If you go in the other direction and just create a `HashSet[object]` for the widest possible assignability, you could create a thread-safe `ConcurrentSet` by wrapping the `HashSet[object]` methods you need to expose in a custom powershell class, and then use a `ReaderWriteLockSlim` to facilitate concurrent reads but exclusive writes:

```bsh
using namespace System.Collections.Concurrent
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
using namespace System.Threading

# Custom IEqualityComparer based on [scriptblock]
# Use [PSComparer]::new({$args[0].Equals($args[1])}) to "restore" default comparer logic
class PSComparer : IEqualityComparer[object]
{
    [scriptblock]
    $Comparer

    PSComparer()
    {
        $this.Comparer = {$args[0] -eq $args[1]}
    }

    PSComparer([scriptblock]$comparer)
    {
        $this.Comparer = $comparer
    }

    [bool]
    Equals($a,$b)
    {
        return & $this.Comparer $a $b
    }

    [int]
    GetHashCode($obj)
    {
        if($obj -is [object]){
            return $obj.GetHashCode()
        }
        throw [System.ArgumentNullException]::new('obj')
    }
}

class ConcurrentSet : IDisposable
{
    hidden [ReaderWriterLockSlim]
    $_lock

    hidden [HashSet[object]]
    $_set

    ConcurrentSet()
    {
        # Default to PowerShell comparison logic, ie. `"1" -eq 1`
        $this.Initialize([PSComparer]::new())
    }

    ConcurrentSet([IEqualityComparer[object]]$comparer)
    {
        $this.Initialize($comparer)
    }

    hidden
    Initialize([IEqualityComparer[object]]$comparer)
    {
        $this._set = [HashSet[object]]::new($comparer)
        $this._lock = [System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim]::new()
    }

    [bool]
    Add([object]$item)
    {
        $this._lock.EnterWriteLock()
        try{
            return $this._set.Add($item)
        }
        finally{
            $this._lock.ExitWriteLock()
        }
    }

    [bool]
    Contains([object]$item)
    {
        $this._lock.EnterReadLock()
        try{
            return $this._set.Contains($item)
        }
        finally{
            $this._lock.ExitReadLock()
        }
    }

    [bool]
    Remove([object]$item)
    {
        $this._lock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock()
        try{
            if($this._set.Contains($item)){
                $this._lock.EnterWriteLock()
                try {
                    return $this._set.Remove($item)
                }
                finally {
                    $this._lock.ExitWriteLock()
                }
            }

            return $false
        }
        finally{
            $this._lock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock()
        }
    }

    UnionWith([IEnumerable[object]]$other)
    {
        $this._lock.EnterWriteLock()
        try{
            $this._set.UnionWith($other)
        }
        finally{
            $this._lock.ExitWriteLock()
        }
    }

    IntersectWith([IEnumerable[object]]$other)
    {
        $this._lock.EnterWriteLock()
        try{
            $this._set.IntersectWith($other)
        }
        finally{
            $this._lock.ExitWriteLock()
        }
    }

    ExceptWith([IEnumerable[object]]$other)
    {
        $this._lock.EnterWriteLock()
        try{
            $this._set.ExceptWith($other)
        }
        finally{
            $this._lock.ExitWriteLock()
        }
    }

    SymmetricExceptWith([IEnumerable[object]]$other)
    {
        $this._lock.EnterWriteLock()
        try{
            $this._set.SymmetricExceptWith($other)
        }
        finally{
            $this._lock.ExitWriteLock()
        }
    }

    [bool]
    IsSubsetOf([IEnumerable[object]]$other)
    {
        $this._lock.EnterReadLock()
        try{
            return $this._set.IsSubsetOf($other)
        }
        finally{
            $this._lock.ExitReadLock()
        }
    }

    [bool]
    IsSupersetOf([IEnumerable[object]]$other)
    {
        $this._lock.EnterReadLock()
        try{
            return $this._set.IsSupersetOf($other)
        }
        finally{
            $this._lock.ExitReadLock()
        }
    }

    [bool]
    IsProperSubsetOf([IEnumerable[object]]$other)
    {
        $this._lock.EnterReadLock()
        try{
            return $this._set.IsProperSubsetOf($other)
        }
        finally{
            $this._lock.ExitReadLock()
        }
    }

    [bool]
    IsProperSupersetOf([IEnumerable[object]]$other)
    {
        $this._lock.EnterReadLock()
        try{
            return $this._set.IsProperSupersetOf($other)
        }
        finally{
            $this._lock.ExitReadLock()
        }
    }

    [bool]
    Overlaps([IEnumerable[object]]$other)
    {
        $this._lock.EnterReadLock()
        try{
            return $this._set.Overlaps($other)
        }
        finally{
            $this._lock.ExitReadLock()
        }
    }

    [bool]
    SetEquals([IEnumerable[object]]$other)
    {
        $this._lock.EnterReadLock()
        try{
            return $this._set.SetEquals($other)
        }
        finally{
            $this._lock.ExitReadLock()
        }
    }

    hidden [int]
    get_Count()
    {
        return $this._set.Count
    }

    Dispose()
    {
        if($this._lock -is [System.IDisposable])
        {
            $this._lock.Dispose()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$tuple = [System.Tuple]::Create("Hello", "World")` could also be `$tuple = [System.Tuple[string,string]]::new("Hello", "World")`. This one could be nice if you need implicit type conversion like `[System.Tuple[string,string]]::new(1, $null)` since Tuple.Create() does not accept null input and it determines type implicitly. That would save the need for some null coalescing in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Another (*ugly*) approach is

```
$MySet = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[[System.Tuple[string,string]]]]::new()
$Tuple = [System.Tuple[string,string]]::new("Test", "Hello")
[void]$MySet.Add($Tuple)

$MySet
```

Result:

```
Item1 Item2 Length
----- ----- ------
Test  Hello      2
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment for the accepted answer, this is what I ended up doing because Tuple.Create() implicitly determines the tuple types and it doesn't accept null inputs.